# How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: (class file version 59.65535)?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I recieved this error when I trying to run a java program with vscode extension:

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class test
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: test (class file version 59.65535) was compiled with preview features that are unsupported. This version of 
    the Java Runtime only recognizes preview features for class file version 60.65535
```

Here is the version of java:

```
java -version
java version "16" 2021-03-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16+36-2231)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16+36-2231, mixed mode, sharing)

javac -version
javac 16
```

This program is running if I only try command java filename.java in cmd, but throws error in vscode neither of the extensions are working(code runner, java debugger/runner).

it would be greatful if you can help me out.

Comment: You compiled your java code with JDK 15 and you are running it with JDK 16. Can you re-compile your code with JDK 16?

Comment: @Abra though OP states that JDK is 16 (`javac 16`) not 15, your advice it is a good place to start - @Abhilash, try to use compatible (or better same) Java versions for both compilation and running

Comment: @Abra thanks for the big help, It started working again only thing I changed is, i moved my file into a new directory. That worked!!

Comment: I had same error, my problem was I overlooked I didn't have `--enable-preview` flag in VM options. The option "Add VM options" in Run Configuration -> Modify options is checkbox and the field can be (and was in my case) hidden.